# Missing index files from elementary repo

Tags: updates, apt, dependencies

After doing a package update I get a 404 error when it's trying to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu/dists/freya/main/binary-i386/Packages

How can I solve that missing dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "FREYA" distribution doesn't exist at ppa:elementary-os/os-patches repository. The correct name is "TRUSTY". To change this you can launch "Software and updates", searching it on Slingshot launcher, or from terminal with the command:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Once launch it, go to "Other software" tab and search for "elementary os-patches" repository url. Edit it and change the "Distribution" field with "trusty". Accept changes and close software-properties-gtk.

Wait for update the cache and error will be corrected.