# Mine apt-get update gives an error?

Tags: system, apt

After i type sudo apt-get update ubuntu shows the following error.

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/freya/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/freya/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 108.160.172.206 80]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All repositories to software runnning over Ubuntu are based on the name of Ubuntu releases. There isn't a release called *Freya* for Ubuntu. That's the name of a elementary OS release.

You must change your source.list.  See the next Q&A to change it:

[update - Missing index files from elementary repo](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4282/565)